# WordPress, enable comments on specific PAGES?

Tags: php, wordpress

I know how to enable/disable comments on all pages. But how can I enable only a few, WITHOUT USING THE UI. In `functions.php` I just wanna go

```
if($this_is_a_page_i_want_comments_on) { enable_comments(); }
```

`enable_comments();` doesn't exist, this is the part I need help with.

I could do this using WordPress Admin by allowing comments on all pages, then going to each page and disabling comments where I don't want them. This would take too long though.

P.S. I'm using Genesis framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply hook to the `comments_open` filter :) If you [look-up in the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L772) how the `comments_open()` function works, you'll notice that the function gets the post in question and then runs it's reposnse through the `comments_open` filter. Here's an example function to override that:

```
function my_override_comments_open( $open ) {
    if ( $this_is_a_page_i_want_comments_on ) {
        $open = true;
    }
    return $open;
}
add_filter('comments_open', 'my_override_comments_open', 1000);
```

I assume that you know how you'll identify the pages that you want to enable comments on - so that's up to you.

PP: I don't know if it will work in Genesis or not(I presume that it should though).

Comment: This looks like what I want. It's not working though, I assume because of how Genesis handles comments. I'll mess with it.

Comment: I don't have genesis to check that out, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_single('page_name_here') || is_single('other_page')) {
    // Show the comment form here
}
```

Not sure if there's a better way, that's just my solution!

Comment: Code for comments is produced by one of theme files. You have to find it in your theme.

Comment: It *can* depend on your theme. Take a look here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form

Comment: @RyanB Well, there's a comments form there. But my CSS doesn't work and it doesn't actually show comments after they're posted. There's not a way to just overwrite the boolean that tells wordpress to enable comments?

Comment: I'd work backwards and start removing things, beginning w/ CSS